# Android development without ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Can I write an app in a .apk file and install it on my device by just transferring it and then open it on my phone? Can I avoid the frustrating complexity of Eclipse and ADT?

Background:

I decided today I wanted to learn developing Android apps. I downloaded the ADT bundle and then spent half the day trying to connect my device so I could run a premade Hello World app on it. After much failure I am frustrated and just want to start writing code.

Comment: Starting new things is always hard! Don't give up!

Comment: Do you think that learning Android application development is going to be any easier than installing and setting up the development tools???

Comment: Not at all, qyoskibum. I didn't have any issue with the ADT at all, my frustration came with my problems to connect my device. I understand I can still write with Eclipse/ADT and transfer the .apk by other means. But if I can avoid the clingy UI of Eclipse, I'm happy

Comment: Getting ADB working has nothing to do with Eclipse.  What do you mean "clingy"?  (Personally, Eclipse for me sucks - try IDEA, or if you are comfortable with pre-release software, Android Studio which is a fork of IDEA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might just be having issues connecting a device. You can and should first get that working outside of Eclipse. You don't mention which host OS you're using, but you'll need to do the following. If you get stuck on any step, just ask.

1. Install the Android SDK.
2. Add the tools to your path.
3. If on Windows, install the USB driver for your device.
4. Connect your device with a USB cable.
5. Enable USB debugging on your device.
6. Open a command or terminal window.
7. Run `adb start-server; adb devices`.
8. Verify that your device is listed.

If your device is listed, then you've successfully connected your device and can use ADB commands to directly install APKs via USB.

Answer (score 1):

If you email the `.apk` to yourself and enable [Install from unknown sources](http://androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources) then you should just be able to tap on it as an attachment in the email, install it and run it.

Similarly, you could install a [file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) app, transfer the `.apk` and open it from there.

*Personally, I find IDEs can be a very resource hungry, slow and unnecessary when I'd much rather use [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/3) for editing and [`gradle`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) on the command line to build, install and debug apps - which is infact what I do, so you may want to give it a go.*

Comment: Why then, does anyone use Eclipse for android development? It seems to be massively overfeatured. Is there anything more than syntax checking, markup and file transfer that makes Eclipse appealing to developers?

Comment: It provides intergrated debugging and much faster deployment (press ▶ and it's on the device and running).

Comment: You also need something to compile the sources into classes, collect all the resources and package them into the apk. This answer trivialises the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Eclipse/ADT, you can try the new(ish) [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), which is built on IntelliJ Idea.

There's no getting around the Android SDK and all of its tooling if you want to develop an Android app, but Android Studio can potentially do a better job of hiding those things from you.

@Tom Leese's answer is the way to go to install an APK on your phone, but you can't really avoid the tools in the long run.  Eventually you'll have to debug, which will require you to get ADB working.

Comment: I'm checking it out now, thanks for the tip. The less technicalities I need to mind, the better!

Answer (score 0):

Try develop with [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=aide).

AIDE is an integrated development environment (IDE) for developing real Android apps directly on your Android device

Comment: I gave up masochism a long time ago.